# Determine sum of exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling to find an answer of the following series

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\exp(a_i+b_ix)}$$

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any information what $a_i$ and $b_i$ are?

Comment: This is no series as it has only $n$ terms... What exactly do you want to calculate?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. What makes you think this series converges? What's the motivation here? It will help to know that.

Comment: $a_i$ and $b_i$ are any number in R. I need to find an equal expression which includes $e^{\sum _i^n a_i}$ and $ e^{\sum _i^n b_i}$

Comment: I don't think you will find an expression in terms of $\exp(\sum a_i)$ and $\exp(\sum b_i)$  Note that if one $a_i$ is very large, the corresponding entry into the sum is essentially zero and doesn't matter.  When you add all the $a_i$ it will dominate.

Comment: It should be $\frac{1}{1+exp(\sum a_i+\sum b_i x)}*f(\sum a_i,\sum b_i x)$ .  problem is finding function $f$

Comment: You won't be able to.  For an example, let all the $b_i$ be zero.  Compare $a_1=a_2=5$ to $a_1=0, a_2=10$  These are not equal, but your expression cannot tell them apart.